# Duda sobre el alcance de las variables en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, variables-globales, alcance

creo que tengo claro que en JS declaras una variable con var o let, esta es global.
Si las declaras dentro de una función locales.

La pregunta es, ¿qué pasa con el alcance de bloque?

Tanto en las estructuras como if, switch, for y while, si declaro una variable dentro de sus llaves, no es accesible desde fuera si las declaro con let, pero si lo son cuando lo hago con var.

No me queda claro porqué ocurre esto y si las variables declaradas en un bloque son locales o globales.

Ejemplo con let:

```
if (condición){
   let numero = 10;
}

console.log(numero)
```

Ejemplo con var:

```
 if (condición){
    var numero = 10;
    }

console.log(numero)
```

Suponiendo que se cumple la condición, la variable numero es accesible si es declarada en el if con la palabra var, en cambio con let no.

Comment: Está claro que `var` y `let` es lo mismo. `var` ya es obsoleto, aunque aún funciona; está reemplazado por `let`. Por otro lado, agrega una estructura de código para tener más respuesta exacta.

Comment: Las palabras reservadas `var` y `let` no son lo mismo ni `var` está obsoleta. En cuanto a tu pregunta, `let` tiene alcance de bloque, mientras que `var` puede extenderse más allá, hasta llegar al ámbito de una función o global, según en dónde haya sido declarada. Puedes leer más al respecto en la documentación existente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora entiendo. ¡Perfecto!

Comment: Busca Hoisting, creo que asi se escribe. En resumen, las variables que declares con `var` se toman todas, y es como si se declararan globalmente hasta arriba del todo. Las que declares con `let` funcionan de la misma forma en la que lo esperarias en otros lenguajes.